# Is this possible to load data into memory using Spark when the Spring Boot Application starts ?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spring-boot

I am new to both Spark and Spring Boot Framework. I have tried to work with 100 million records of a database in a spark cluster of 3 nodes having 16 Gigs of RAM each and 4 cores, after I cached the complete 100 million records in memory it works really fast, so my main goal is to load and cache the records in memory when my spring boot application (which I am writing to make some RESTful Services that will operate on spark context) starts. How can I exactly load and cache 100 million records at the time of application startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen the application starts and start a thread to load your records.

```
public class CacheLoadListener implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            //Start a thread/job to load your data
        }
    }
}
```

In a config file

```
@Bean
public CacheLoadListener cacheLoadListener() {
    return new CacheLoadListener();
}
```